# tgetent() not found while compiling vim

Tags: ubuntu, vim, ncurses

Currently I'm trying to install the YouCompleteMe extension to my vim setup, but it requires my vim to have the version of 7.3.584 or higher. The vim shipped with my Ubuntu 12.10 is 7.3.547, so I had to recompile vim from source following [this instrucion](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Building-Vim-from-source).

As the instruction says, I executed:

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev libgnome2-dev libgnomeui-dev \
libgtk2.0-dev libatk1.0-dev libbonoboui2-dev \
libcairo2-dev libx11-dev libxpm-dev libxt-dev python-dev ruby-dev mercurial
```

which should give me all the packages needed for the compilation. However, when I've cloned the vim source and just about to start tweak the configuration for compilation, I got

```
...
checking for tgetent in -lcurses... yes
termcap library is not usable
no terminal library found
checking for tgetent()... configure: error: NOT FOUND!
    You need to install a terminal library; for example ncurses.
    Or specify the name of the library with --with-tlib.
```

I did some research, and got the general sense that I should specify ncurses as my terminal library. But when I did

```
./configure --with-tlib=ncurses
```

it yells back

```
...
checking --with-tlib argument... ncurses
chekcing for linking with ncurses library... OK
chekcing for tgetent()... configure: error: NOT FOUND!
    You need to install a terminal library; for example ncurses.
    Or specify the name of the library with --with-tlib.
```

I don't know if there is anything I've been missing, or if there is another way to get the newest version of vim? Many thanks!

Comment: The error basically says you need the ncurses dev packages. Which is called "**libncurses5-dev** - developer's libraries for ncurses".

Comment: @Shiki That I did install, per the instruction listed above :/

Comment: Whoops. Sorry..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using [that guy's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~pi-rho/+ppa-packages) to keep Vim up-to-date on Ubuntu 11.04. The latest version is 7.3.854 which, I believe, works with YouCompleteMe.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Now the version's up. Thanks!

Comment: @alxyzc - This is why you should create a PPA on Launchpad, and copy there your fav packages.

Comment: @Shiki Fully noted :)

Answer (score 7):

This is because the system lacks the ncurses library, which can be resolved by installing libncurses5-dev.

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev
```

I solved it through this article.
[enter link description here](https://vimjc.com/install-vim-and-vimcdoc.html)

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same issue (recompiling vim to use YCM), and I fixed it by removing `src/auto/config.cache` (in the vim tree) and re-running `./configure`. It seems an outdated `configure` cache was still there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running ubuntu 16.10 and couldn't get vim 8.0 to compile.  Googling the issue told me to install a package "ncurses-dev" but I couldn't find that package. I finally found that installing package "libtinfo-dev" did the trick and I was able to compile vim.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu (and other Debian-based distos) you can get all required prerequisites with:

```
$ sudo apt-get build-dep vim-gnome
```

I don't know if that fixes the dependency problem, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but when I did this, `Picking 'vim' as source package instead of 'vim-gnome'` Looks like it didn't work for me.